# knex insert multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have a problem inserting many rows into postgres db with knex.
I have dynamic number of rows needed to be inserted. The result i expect is:

insert row four times (four is for an example. I dont know exact number of inserts as it comes dynamically from frontend):

- **field_id** will be diffrent in every row: (1,2,3,4) - i have array of these ID's
- **id_of_product** will be always the same
- **value** will be always diffrent: (req.body[id] that comes from Frontend) - ID in brackets is same value as the **field_id** from an
  array

How i can achieve that? I tried looping it with forEach, but it's async operation so i can't use .then() as it will be called four times

Here's what i tried. i dont know how to set field_id and req.body to take it dynamically.

fields = [1,2,3,4]

Expected result:

knex creates 4 inserts as follows:
**field_id:** 1,
**product_id:** some static id
**value:** frontValue[1]
ETC

```
knex('metadata').insert(
 [{ field_id: fields, 
    product_id: product_id, 
    value: req.body[fields] 
 }]
)
```

Comment: [`insert()`](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert) can accept an array of rows to insert.

Comment: Tried it but that doesn't seem to work for me, or i make something wrong

`knex('metadata').insert([{
          field_id: fields,
          product_id: product_id,
          value: req.body[fields]
        }])`

Here's what i tried. i dont know how to set field_id and req.body to take it dynamically as fields is an array of ID's

Comment: Can you update your question with how you attempted to call insert?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: you have to be more declarative with what you are doing, when you pass an array with a single element to knex it is only going to attempt to insert *one* item. I'll post the correct usage below

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to insert 4 records to your `metadata` table:

```
{ field_id: 1, product_id: X, value: req.body[1] },
{ field_id: 2, product_id: X, value: req.body[2] },
{ field_id: 3, product_id: X, value: req.body[3] },
{ field_id: 4, product_id: X, value: req.body[4] }
```

To insert multiple records in the same statement they each need to be *separate* elements in the array that you supply to Knex (check out the [`insert`](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-insert) docs for additional examples):

```js
const product_id = X;
const fieldsToInsert = fields.map(field => 
  ({ field_id: field, product_id, value: req.body[field] })); 

return knex('metadata').insert(fieldsToInsert)
  .then(() => { /* handle success */ })
  .catch(() => { /* handle failure */});
```

Comment: is it possible to do operation knex - where - update similar way? Update multiple rows bases on array of id's